# meteor js can't login with social accounts after integrating stripe checkout

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

i am working on meteor(v 1.3) app that allows their users to login with facebook and twitter .Users also could pay online using strip chekout. Before implementing stripe chekout library, i tested the app i was able to login with facebook and twitter. I also tested the payment and it is working (test mode).The problem is after integrating the stripe checkout i'm not able to login with facebook nor twitter. The console print this worning :

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A      warning will be added to the URL wwww.myapplication.com

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn

Comment: Are you using chrome to test? try with other browser to see if the problem still occurs

Comment: firefox and chrome, same warning